# How to change OPENSSLDIR CentOs

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, centos

I tried to get the version of OpenSSL but it returns a warning message:

```
WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
```

The location of `OPENSSLDIR` is incorrect. `./config` does not do anything.

How can i change this?

Comment: Please state the version of OpenSSL you are using. There are slightly different behaviors from `--prefix` and `--openssldir` depending on the version. You should also provide your configure line. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
built on: Wed May  6 23:37:56 PDT 2015
platform: linux-x86_64

Comment: For OpenSSL 1.0.1, just run configure with `--openssldir`. I don't believe you need ``-prefix` for that version. Maybe something like `./Configure shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl`.